# Ruby - DSL using instance variables

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, dsl

The code here is a simplification of the bigger solution.  I'm trying to figure out how
to make a ruby DSL that "reads" nicely.  The first block of code; works (works for now)
I would like to know how to write the DSL

The core of the problem is that while the class is being processed, it doesn't have an instance variables for me to work with.  IE: @match_code

Does anyone know of a simpler more elegant solution?  The entirety of code must kept with in a class.

## Want I want it to look like is:

```
class MatchStuff 
  include ProcessBase

  match 'account' do | event |
    pp event
  end
end

matcher = MatchStuff.new
matcher.accept 'account'
```

## Current working (not so nice) code

```
class ProcessBase
  def initialize
    @match_code = []
  end

  def match(string_match, &block)
    @match_code.push([string_match, block])
  end

  def accept(test_str)
    @match_code.each do | test_block |
      if test_str == test_block[0])
        test_block[1].call test
      end
    end
  end
end

class MatchStuff < ProcessBase
  def initialize 
    super

    match 'account' do | event |
      pp event
    end
  end
end

test = MatchStuff.new
test.accept 'account'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use methods from `ProcessBase` in the body of `class MatchStuff`, you can `extend` it in addition to `include`ing or subclassing it:

```
class MatchStuff
  include ProcessBase
  extend ProcessBase

  match 'account' do |event|
    pp event
  end
end
```

But then you have the problem that `@match_code` refers to a class instance variable in `match`, but a regular instance variable in `accept`. I'd add a reader method to `ProcessBase` and use it on the class in `accept`, so you always use the class instance variable. Then you can use `||=` to avoid needing the `initialize` method (which won't get called for the class when you `extend`).

```
module ProcessBase
  # reader method, autovivifying to empty Array
  def match_code
    @match_code ||= []
  end

  def match(string_match, &block)
    # using the reader here, on self, which is the class
    match_code.push([string_match, block])
  end

  def accept(test_str)
    # here, self is the instance, so we have to explicitly get the class
    # and access match_code from there
    self.class.match_code.each do | test_block |
      if test_str == test_block[0])
        test_block[1].call test
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Alternatively, you could put `match` (with the `match_code` reader) and `accept` in separate modules, `extend` one and `include` the other. That has the advantage of not giving your instances a `match` method that doesn't work (because it uses the wrong `match_code`). You could even define an `included` or `extended` method that does one when you do the other.

```
module ProcessClassBase
  def match_code
    # as above
  end

  def match
    # as above
  end
end

module ProcessInstanceBase
  def accept
    # as above
  end

  def included(other_mod)
    other_mod.extend(ProcessClassBase)
  end
end

class MatchStuff
  include ProcessInstanceBase # now this also extends ProcessClassBase

  match 'account' do |event|
    pp event
  end
end
```

It's probably worth noting that this all breaks if you subclass `MatchStuff`. Instances of the subclass (call it `MatchStuffSub`), when `accept` is called, will try to access `MatchStuffSub.match_code` instead of `MatchStuff.match_code` (where `match` puts stuff).

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't think to store the code in a class variable!

Answer (score 0):

Define `MatchStuff` as

```
class MatchStuff < ProcessBase
   def set_match
      match 'account' do |event|
        pp event
      end
   end
end
```

and call `set_match` from the `ProcessBase` constructor:

```
class ProcessBase
  def initialize
    @match_code = []
    set_match # Must be defined in derived class
  end
  ...
end
```

Since you're not specifying a constructor for `MatchStuff` it will automatically call the parent class constructor.

This achieves what I interpret your goal to be, which is to specify the `'account'` string and associated block in `MatchStuff` in as minimal a way as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could just try not using instance variables. It's not clear on what the possible values of the match strings might look like so I gave an example of how you might want to make them "safe" for this method.

```
module ProcessBase
  def self.included(c)
    c.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def match(string_match, &block)
      method = string_match.downcase.gsub(/\s+/,'_').to_sym
      define_method(method, &block)
    end
  end

  def accept(string_match)
    method = string_match.downcase.gsub(/\s+/,'_').to_sym
    self.send(method, 'test')
  end
end

class MatchStuff
  include ProcessBase

  match 'account' do | event |
    pp event
  end
end

test = MatchStuff.new
test.accept 'account'
```

Comment: the string_match would come up multiple times.  I was looking for something similar to the a pub/sub system with multiple listeners.  The above response, only allows for one.